# Spring Constant Dependence on Contact Area

Tags: material-science, collision, simulations, spring

I'm actually modeling a contact situation between an elastic cuboid (in reality it is an elastomer) and a non elastic sphere ($c_c\ll c_s$). The spring constant $c$ is defined with the young's modulus $E$, the area $A$ and the height of the cuboid $h$ with
$$c=\frac{A\cdot E}{h}$$
However, the contact area in the described model changes with the indentation depth. So in my opinion the equation in this model  should depend on the indentation depth $x$
$$c(x)=\frac{A(x)\cdot E}{h}$$

Am I right, or do I mess something up?

Comment: You are right about the non-linearity of contact problems. See http://www.mech.utah.edu/~me7960/lectures/Topic7-ContactStressesAndDeformations.pdf for some example force/contact area calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somewhat more complicated than this.  To get it right, you'll need to look at the theory of elasticity.  There is a model, called the Hertzian model which deals with the force between things like two elastic spheres or a sphere and an infinite space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_mechanics).

In the case of an a hard sphere and an infinite elastic space which has Young's modulus $E$ and is incompressible $\nu=1/2$, the force of indentation can be shown to be
$$
F= \frac{16E}{9}R^{1/2}\delta^{3/2},
$$
where $\delta$ is the indentation depth, and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

Now, you have a finite thickness elastic material, Dimitriadis et al. have shown be shown that if $\chi=\sqrt{R\delta}/h$ is small,
$$
F=\frac{16E}{9}R^{1/2}\delta^{3/2}\left[1+0.884\chi+0.781\chi^2+O(\chi^3)\right].
$$
For details, here is the reference:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1302067/pdf/11964265.pdf